# How to write complicated query like this?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have table reports which contain:

```
rid     reparti
R00001  Ortopedi
R00002  Kardiologji
R00003  Gjinekologji
```

Table doctors which contain:

```
did      demri    dmbiemri  titullli      rruga        qyteti    kp     shteti  mob         fix       email                 rid     paga
D00001   Shaban   Merovci   Dr Familjar   Mic Sokoli   Vushtrri  42000  Kosove  37744842203 28570369  shmerovci@gmail.com   R00001  1000
```

Table appointments:

```
tid     pid     did     rid     data_koha  konfirmimi
T00001  P00001  D00010  R00002  2015-12-20 08:30:00 1
T00002  P00009  D00004  R00003  2015-12-25 10:30:00 1
```

Table hospilization (without appointments you can't have hospitalization):

```
  hpid    pid     did     data_shtrimi  sid      terapia    diagnoza         tid
HP0001  P00009  D00004  2015-12-13    S00001   Barera     Hemorislapaskus  T00002
HP0002  P00006  D00002  2015-12-22    S00010   Kimoterapi Fragaria vesca   T00008
HP0003  P00001  D00002  2015-12-20    S00008   Barera     Depresion        T00001
```

Table bills which contains:

```
 fid     pid     hpid    cmimi_patvsh  tvsh  cmimi_metvsh data_fatures
    F00001  P00002  HP0005  85.00         0.18  100.30       2016-02-13
    F00002  P00009  HP0001  700.00        0.18  826.00       2016-12-10
    F00003  P00001  HP0003  120.00        0.18  141.60       2015-12-29
```

My purpose is to find for each report numbers of doctors (did) as NrDoktoreve which work on it, avg (paga) as PagaMesatare for that repart, number of hospitalization as NrHospitalizimeve realized this year, sum of bills (values cmimi_patvsh,values cmimi_metvsh) realized this year. All of this should be should in one dataset list.

Of course those tables contain more data I just put here some examples.

Comment: Show us what you have tried or [Learn SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

Comment: the expected results output (TABLE) is not shown in question. Please improve this next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is not too complicated, the approach is to identify the join columns (where the tables fit together), write the joins, group the table by RID (for you want all results per RID), finally choose the fields. 
I do not have a MySQL available for testing, but the query should look like this:

```
select 
    rid,
    count(distinct did) NrDoktoreve, 
    avg(cmimi_metvsh) as PagaMesatare,
    count(distinct hpid) as NrHospitalizimeve,
    sum(cmimi_patvsh),
    sum(cmimi_metvsh)
        from reparts r 
        left join appointments a on r.rid = a.rid 
        left join hospitalization h on a.tod = h.tid 
        left join doctors d on r.rid = d.rid
        left join bills b on a.pid = b.pid
    group by rid
    order by rid;
```

If you are not comfortable about writing SQL, you may consider graphical tools like DbSchema (http://www.dbschema.com/) (just one example out of many tools available, but it works fine with MySQL).

Comment: thanks but when you make join reparts with  appointments than many repart in which there no appointment is not showed , i need to show all of them!

Comment: you may try left joins then: select ... from repart LEFT JOIN ... another_table .... -> everything from the left table is taken, plus matches from the right one if these exist.

Comment: it is just replacing the joins by LEFT JOIN. Perhaps you have to change the order of the joins or make not all to left join to get exactly the result that you need.

Comment: Hope I could help you :-)

Comment: i used inner and left join but than problem was to specified interval time which was condition of task.

Comment: i found a solution of my problem and i thank you for prefering me left join

Comment: Appreciated! Please accept my post as answer if satisfied. Good luck with your task...